# Best way to return more than 1 item from Web method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I Have a situation like this.

I have to populate 2 **labels** and 1 **drop-down list** in the UI with a call to  a Web-method.

As the function is static , I am unable to access the page elements (labels and drop-down list ) from within the web-method. So I am trying to return the HTML that I want.

```
 [WebMethod()]
    public static object[]  GetStatus()
    {
        //Return text for Label1;

        //Return text for Label2;

        //Return items to display in ListBox  [Number of items can vary]

    }
```

I think object[] may work ..But is it the best way to handle this situation ? Also considering the java script code needed to set the value for these controls (after calling the web-method) what is the best practice in such scenarios ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a ViewModel class.

```
public class StatusViewModel
{
    public string Label1 { get; set; }
    public string Label2  { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> ListBox { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod()]
public static StatusViewModel  GetStatus()
{
    // do work
    return new StatusViewMode....

}
```

Comment: +1 if you show how to use that, both on the client and the server.

Answer (score 3):

How about `string[]`? Have you tried that?

Comment: @John..+1. Well not yet..I wanted to know what are best practices before I start..

Comment: Best practice is to do the simplest thing that works. You want a number of strings: simplest is to send an array of strings. If the number were larger than three or four, then I'd return an object with one property per string value. If you had more than one type of thing to return, then I'd immediately use an object.

Answer (score 2):

Create a composite object and return that.

```
public class combinedObject{
  public string Labe11;
  public string Label2;
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create custom object witch containing matching properties. then write a custom serialization to serialize and deserialize.